# Reversing Mobius Inversion?

Tags: number-theory

So I am aware that Mobius Inversion tells us if we have a function $f$ on $\mathbb N$, and define $g(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}f(d)$, then we may recover $f$ from $g$ by:

$f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius Function.

However, suppose that we have a function $g$ on the integers and know that for some $f$, we have:

$g(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n)f(\frac{n}{d})$. How many such functions $f$ are there?

For example could there exist two distinct functions $f,f_1$ such that:

$g(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d )f(\frac{n}{d}) = \sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d)f_1(\frac{n}{d})$?

Comment: No, in that case $f$ must be $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} g(d)$. Mobius inversion is invertible.

Comment: No, because you then have $f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}g(d)=f_1(n)$.

Comment: Dirichlet convolution by $\mu(n)$ is inversible because $\mu(1) \ne 0$